# Segfault triggered by multiple GPUs

Tags: caffe

I am running a training script with `caffe` on a 8 GPU (1080Ti) server.

If I train on 6 or fewer gpus (using `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES`), everything is fine.

(I set `export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0,1,2,3,4,5` and specify these GPUs in training script.)

But if I train on 7 or 8 GPUs, I see this error at the start of training consistently:

````
Error: (unix time) try if you are using GNU date
SIGSEGV (@0x70) received by PID 17206 (TID 0x7fc678ffd700) from PID 112; stack trace:
@     0x7fc86186b4b0 (unknown)
@     0x7fc861983f75 (unknown)
@     0x7fc863c4b4c7 std::__cxx11::basic_string<>::_M_construct<>()
@     0x7fc863c4c60b _ZN5caffe2db10LMDBCursor5valueB5cxx11Ev
@     0x7fc863ace3e7 caffe::AnnotatedDataLayer<>::DataLayerSetUp()
@     0x7fc863a6e4d5 caffe::BasePrefetchingDataLayer<>::LayerSetUp()
@     0x7fc863cbf2b4 caffe::Net<>::Init()
@     0x7fc863cc11ae caffe::Net<>::Net()
@     0x7fc863bb9c9a caffe::Solver<>::InitTestNets()
@     0x7fc863bbb84d caffe::Solver<>::Init()
@     0x7fc863bbbb3f caffe::Solver<>::Solver()
@     0x7fc863ba7d61 caffe::Creator_SGDSolver<>()
@     0x7fc863ccc1c2 caffe::Worker<>::InternalThreadEntry()
@     0x7fc863cf94c5 caffe::InternalThread::entry()
@     0x7fc863cfa38e boost::detail::thread_data<>::run()
@     0x7fc85350d5d5 (unknown)
@     0x7fc83fee56ba start_thread
@     0x7fc86193d41d clone
@                0x0 (unknown)```
````

The `Error: (unix time) ...` at the start of the trace is apparently [thrown by `glog`](https://hpc.nih.gov/development/glog.html).

It appears to be thrown when a general failure happens.

[This thread](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/1993) show many different issues triggering `Error: (unix time)...` and similar trace.

In the thread, it is noted that multiple GPUs may trigger this error.

That is what appears to be the root cause in my case.

Are there things I can further look into to understand what is happening?

Comment: The segfault is being triggered in `caffe::db::LMDBCursor::value[abi:cxx11]() `

Comment: @talonmies thanks for clarifying that it is not a CUDA error.